# Using data with different files

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display the name that the user enters in the text field, but when I launch the app, it only shows 'The player is'. I tried to assign the value of player1Name immediately to a string and it worked

This is my first view

```
class PlayerList : ObservableObject {
    @Published var player1Name = ""
    }
struct Player : Identifiable {
    var name : String
    let id = UUID()
}
struct ViewJouer: View {
    @ObservedObject var player = PlayerList()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter player name", text: $player.player1Name)
}
```

This is my second view:

```
struct ViewTest: View {
    @ObservedObject var player = PlayerList()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("The player is \(player.player1Name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: `ViewJouer` and `ViewTest` are using different instances of `PlayerList` (ie, they aren't sharing data)

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to use `ObservableObject` and manage data in your app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app  very easy to understand and to use, just copy and paste the relevant example into your code.